# How to generate auto-increment row IDs in apache drill

Tags: apache, apache-drill

Is there any way to create auto-increment row IDs in drill so that whenever I insert a new record into the table, a unique row ID will automatically generated for that record?

Thanks!

Comment: please share more details.

Answer (score 1):

Drill is not used for insertion, update or delete. It is used only for **querying**.

You can only save your query output as *csv, parquet or json* file in your local file system using [CTAS](http://drill.apache.org/docs/create-table-as-ctas-command/) command. Also, [drop](https://drill.apache.org/docs/drop-table/) files from local file system.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Drill can be used for CTAS, creating new tables (files) as the output of a query.

I have (yet!) been able to find an autoincrement function, and have dropped back to unix primitives:

```
awk '{print NR"|"$0}' ./104.10xallevents.psv/0_0_0.psv
```